# Populate UITableView via a string?

Tags: ios, json, string, uitableview, nsarray

I have a simple iOS app which parses multiple JSON feeds and stores the data in multiple strings. I know exactly which strings to use for what and how long the count is because the JSON feeds are feeds that I control from some of my websites.

However, even though I have specified this in the "tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, the UITableView still won't populate..

Is this because I am using strings to populate the UITableView? And if so, do you HAVE to use arrays to populate a UITableView.

Thanks for you're time :)

UPDATE: Here is m code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Printing table view.");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AccountCell *cell = (AccountCell *)[account_table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AccountCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex: 0];

        // Draws the cell background.
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiFeedletsnglass5.png"]];

        // Draws the pressed cell background.
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-on.png"]];

        // Round of edges of content view in Carousel.
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

        cell.profilepic.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        cell.profilepic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.profilepic.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        cell.profilepic.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    }

    if ((facebook_printed == 0) && (logged_facebook == 1)) {
        NSString *full_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", facebook_first_name, facebook_last_name];
        cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", full_name];
        cell.account_type_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Facebook"];

        NSData *facebook_imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: facebook_proffile_pic]];
        UIImage *facebook_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:facebook_imageData];
        cell.profilepic.image = facebook_image;

        facebook_printed = 1;
    }

    else if ((youtube_printed == 0) && (logged_youtube == 1)) {
        cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", youtube_profilename];
        cell.account_type_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YouTube"];

        NSData *youtube_imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: youtube_profilepic]];
        UIImage *youtube_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:youtube_imageData];
        cell.profilepic.image = youtube_image;

        youtube_printed = 1;
    }

    else if ((instagram_printed == 0) && (logged_instagram == 1)) {
        cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", instagram_name_tag];
        cell.account_type_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Instagram"];

        NSData *instagram_imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: instagram_profilepicture]];
        UIImage *instagram_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:instagram_imageData];
        cell.profilepic.image = instagram_image;

        instagram_printed = 1;
    }

    else if ((googleplus_printed == 0) && (logged_googleplus == 1)) {
        cell.username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", googleplus_profilename];
        cell.account_type_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Google Plus"];

        NSData *googleplus_imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: googleplus_profilepic]];
        UIImage *googleplus_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:googleplus_imageData];
        cell.profilepic.image = googleplus_image;

        googleplus_printed = 1;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't have to use an array, but you do need to return a number in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:. Are you doing that? Show your code.

Comment: For now your question doesn't have any sense. Could you provide some details/code snippets?

Comment: Well for numberOfRowsInSection I have set that to 5 as there are 5 items to load. What is weird is that the tableview units with 5 empty cells when viewDidLoad is called. However, when I call [json_tabel reloadData] ...  nothing seems to happen. The cellForRowAtIndexPath does NOT get called.

Comment: I have updated my post with my code as well.

Comment: You'd be getting and error if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't getting called as it is a required delegate method. How are you breaking up your string to use it as data for the table?

Comment: Ah right. hmmm... I wander what it could be then. (By the way I have checked all my NSStrings and they ALL store the correct data I want to show).

Comment: Are you sure your table view's dataSource and delegate properties are set?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. I have connected my UITableView to the tableview outlet, dataSource and delegate in the Interface builder. Also in my header file I have added: <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: So is `Printing table view.` getting logged?  If so how many times?

Comment: @ansible Oh no thats some other check I have in the app so it know what to print in each of the 5 cells. And yes I have used the debugger to make sure only one of them IS true at any time during cellForRowAtIndexPath method. So they if statements are not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reloading the table view's data once you obtain the value of the string?

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Well I am calling reloadData when I have finished parsing the JSON files and storing the data I need in the NSStrings. But it reloadData method doesn't actually do anything.... And whats weird is that reloadData seems to happen on viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear even though I have put NO code in those methods at all....

Answer (score 0):

Right after much frustration and pretty much a lot of trial and error I finally figured out that it is because of `if (cell == nil)` that my Custom Cell was not loading (showing in the UITableView).

I was not aware of this at all, but from what I have read online it seems that when using UiTableViews in Storyboard UI's with Custom Cells, you are NOT meant to use the control statement `if (cell == nil)`

Thanks to everyone who commented on this post though. I appreciate you're help.